# Verificación de las Keys de twitter

Tags: python, twitter-api, oauth

estoy intentando aprender python con el libro " Learning-Python-Networking-Second-Edition " y el siguiente código no me funciona, en todo momento de dice que las credenciales son invalidas:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import requests, requests_oauthlib, sys

def init_auth(file):

    (CONSUMER_KEY,
     CONSUMER_SECRET,
     OAUTH_TOKEN,
     OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET) = open(file, 'r').read().splitlines()
     
    auth_obj = requests_oauthlib.OAuth1(
    CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
    OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
    
    if verify_credentials(auth_obj):
        print('Validated credentials OK')
        return auth_obj
    else:
        print('Credentials validation failed')
        sys.exit(1)

def verify_credentials(auth_obj):
    url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
    response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_obj)
    return response.status_code == 200
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    auth_obj = init_auth('credentials.txt')
```

las KEY's las estoy cogiendo de "API Key and Secret"  y "Access Token and Secret" de la pagina de mi API de twitter, alguien sabe donde me equivoco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Son 4 keys que tienes que [generar](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard) y tu APP tiene que tener un [nivel de acceso](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve%22,%22code%22:453) mayor al Essential.

[image]

Una vez cumplas con lo anterior, puedes comprobar que tus credenciales sean validas asi:

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session

consumer_key = "API Key"
consumer_secret = "API Key Secret"
access_token= "Access Token"
access_token_secret= "Access Token Secret"

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'

oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
)

response = oauth.get(url)
print("status_code:", response.status_code, "\ntext:", response.text)
```

Comment: eso ya lo he hecho, también he probado a regenerar las key varias veces sin éxito, puede ser que desde la publicación del libro halla cambiado la url de verificación o algo?,  si imprimo el valor de auth_obj, el resultado es ''' http://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json <requests_oauthlib.oauth1_auth.OAuth1 object at 0x0000020560868BB30>'''

Comment: El código funciona. Seria bueno ver cual es el mensaje que te devuelve twitter cuando haces la solicitud. Podrías añadir después de la línea `response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_obj)` esta línea `print("Status code:", response.status_code, "\ntext:", response.text)` y decirme que te sale?

Comment: muchas gracias por contestarme, he puerto el print donde me has dicho y el resultado es este:  `Status code: 401   text: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}`

Comment: Edite la respuesta para que veas como tengo las key en el archivo.
Ese error indica que "*Hubo un problema al autenticar su solicitud. Esto podría deberse a credenciales de autenticación faltantes o incorrectas. Esto también puede ser devuelto en otras circunstancias no definidas*", [así lo explica twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting#http-status-codes). 
Efectivamente, el error lo pude replicar al copiar mal las key en el archivo. Por favor, verifica que las key no contengan espacio o caracteres diferentes de los que te ha dado Twitter.

Comment: es que lo extraño es lo que te digo que me sale si le digo que me imprima la URL, si después de la línea `response = requests.get(url, auth=auth_obj)` le pongo un `print("response ", url, auth_obj)` lo que obtengo es `response   http://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json <requests_oauthlib.oauth1_auth.OAuth1 object at 0x00000249D650BB30>`, yo creo que por algo no crea la URL de forma correcta

Comment: El print que pusiste imprime tres valores: el string "response", la url y el objeto oauth que se encarga de generar los headers para que Twitter acepte la solicitud. Si te animas podemos ir comprobando para ver que está fallando. He editado la respuesta y añadido más código para comprobar si las key que tienes de tu aplicación si tienen la capacidad de obtener el código de acceso (OAuth token). Asígnale el valor a estas dos variable `consumer_key` y `consumer_secret` y coméntame que te sale por consola

Comment: bueno, pues el código que me has pasado funciona, el resultado de la consola es el string de **tu aplicacion si pudo obtner el OAuth token**, estoy pensando que no sea de la configuración de api de twitter, podría ser??

Comment: Perfecto, ahora vamos a comprobar si el Acceso token (las claves de tu usuario) son validas! he editado el código y añadido dos variables más `access_token` y `access_token_secret` complétalas y por favor, coméntame que te sale. Como ves, autorizarte con el Auth de twitter es toda una odisea, pero no te desanimes, por lo general solo hay que ir probando hasta encontrar que está fallando

Comment: Pues nada, según tu código tanto unas, como otras son correctas, el resultado de ejecutar el código es la cadena **Tu aplicación tiene el access token y el secreto de tu cuenta de Twitter.**

Comment: puedes hacer `response.text` y ver los metadatos de tu cuenta de usuario que te devuelve twitter

Comment: algo marcha mal, he probado a ejecutar tu código con la variables vacías y sigo obteniendo la cadena de que los access y el secreto son correctos...., ahora si que no lo entiendo, con las variables vacías no debería de funcionar

Comment: Si, tienes razón. Olvide añadirle el if para comprobar el status_code de la respuesta. Vuelve a comprobar a ver que te sale con el código que edite

Comment: bueno, ahora me da un error en el raise: ¨¨raise
RuntimeError: No active exception to reraise¨¨, pero te he de decir que en la version anterior le añadí un ¨¨ print(response.text)¨¨ después del print del try  y me arrojo lo siguiente:¨¨{"errors":[{"message":"You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve","code":453}]}
¨¨

Comment: Oh, ahora todo tiene sentido. Tu aplicación tiene acceso limitado y es necesario que le solicites a twitter más acceso. Lo tienes que hacerlo en ingles. Yo lo intente ayer y me aceptaron enseguida. Ve al enlace que te dicen y responde que eres estudiante y nuevo en programación, en la pregunta si tu aplicación va enviar twit, retwittear o enviar mensajes directos, y más... le dices que no, porque eso requiere un acceso mucho mayor

Comment: ostras, muchas gracias, me estaba volviendo loco. de verdad, muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Un gusto, @Javier, voy a reeditar la respuesta para macar los puntos claves en tener en cuenta. Marcala como correcta y de esa manera tu puedas ayudar a otros a encontrar la solución